# What is the right approach when no handler is found in the call stack in C# program

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I ask this question because soon I'll have interview heavily focused on error handling but also this is something I haven't figure out even though I have almost 7 months as a junior C# developer.

As the title says I want to know what is the right way to deal with exceptions form which there is no appropriate error handler. Some time ago I've heard a colleague of mine talking about generic exception handler (whatever that may mean) which is responsible to deal with suck case scenarios. However I did I little googling I haven't been able to find some information about such a thing.

So my question is - how to deal with those kind of exceptions and my subquestion is - is there really something called generic exception handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there really something called generic exception handler?

Yes - that's what they call the handler that logs the exception and stores as much info as possible before quitting the program. One way to set up a handler like that is adding a handler to the [`UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event of your `AppDomain` object.

It is neither "generic" nor a "handler" in the .NET sense, because no generic types are involved, and because the actions the handler could take are rather limited. Unlike a real handler which could block or re-throw the exceptions that it handles, the last-chance "handler" could see what's been thrown, but cannot cause the execution to continue.

Comment: I see, thinking about it I recon that this was exactly what he has been doing. I was looking for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught exceptions will result in applicaiton crash. You can subscribe to AppDomain.UnhandeledException event to get notified about such situation, write some message in log, e.t.c.

However, you cannot prevent applicaiton from crashing in that handler, because there will be no point from which the execution could continue.

Answer (score 1):

The way you deal with unplanned exceptions is to catch them, log them to some place where a developer will review them for bugs, and then abort the action that way just being tried. This might mean that you show the user an error message, that you shut down the application or that you let a framework like ASP.NET handle the exception (it will "handle" it by showing a generic error page).

Unplanned exceptions can always occur due to bugs. You need a strategy to deal with that (as described above).

A "generic" exception handler would be a `catch (Exception ex)`. In other words, a catch-all. That is not an official term, but that's what the person meant.